# Formula or function for getting salesperson monthly sales average

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

| Salesperson | JANUARY | FEBRUARY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SALES TYPE 1 | '=January Ave | '=February Ave |
| SALES TYPE 2 | '=January Ave | '=February Ave |

I need help figuring out what formulas/nested functions I would use in the January and February average columns in the above table.  The Excel document I'm working with has a tab for each sales person.  In these tabs include the above table-like scorecard element.

I'm using the old "Sharing" feature of Excel which has a lot of limitations, you can't have tables in the document for example (experts, correct me if I am wrong about this) this is why I'm hoping to use a formula to get, calculate and input the data where it needs to go.

There is another tab where all the data is stored in a table-like structure.  It has columns for the date of the sale, the ID of the sales person and how many sales were made on that day.

I'm also worried that too complicated of a formula being done 24 times in each sheet and there being a total of 50 sheets in the document, would this cause the document to lag?  I'm  reading on index match vs xlookup, I hear sumifs is easy but the file doesn't work as fast with that?

What formulas would you use?  Any advice how to make sure the document runs smoothly when users use it?  Any advice here is welcome.  Thanks in advance for you patience.

Comment: Did you try `AVERAGEIFS()` function?